# Align horizontal ul to bottom of image

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, alignment

I've got a horizontal UL and I'm trying to align it to the bottom of an image.

They're both inside a div. I've googled it and tried setting the ul to "position: absolute; bottom: 0" among other things.

Example: http://murielbrandolini.com/ (done in flash, but I'm using html/css)

Thanks

Comment: what is your question can you please explain what you want and what have you tried up-till now.

Comment: Do you have some code to try? Make sure to set your menu container to `position:relative` for your positioning to work.

Comment: You have no code here, no details on what you're trying to accomplish, (aligned where?? Left, center?). Any answer would only be a guess at what you want.

Comment: You should add some additional details and probably a snippet of your html and css or there is a good chance this question will be closed before you get any answers...

Comment: I haven't added any code because I thought it was generic enough (common horizontal ul, trying to align it with an image). I've stated what I want above. And yes I've stated position: relative in my menu container. If you do want to see the code, I uploaded it here http://jsfiddle.net/gaY4t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell what effect you are trying to accomplish from the demo you posted on the comments above, but is is this what you meant by aligning your menu to the bottom of an image?

http://jsfiddle.net/gaY4t/1/

Comment: I've got that, but it's overlaying on top of the image. Though thanks anyways